# It seems like AWS rekognition detect labels is timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda, amazon-rekognition

I'm building this as a Maven project, I've imported the dependency for rekognition:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-rekognition</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Here's my handle request for the lambda function:

```
@Override
    public AnalyzeTrickResponse handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
        logger = context.getLogger();
        logger.log("Loading Java Lambda handler of AnalyzeTrick");
        logger.log(input.toString());
        
        AnalyzeTrickResponse response;
        
        String photo = "girrafe.jpg";
        String bucket = "trickapp";


        AmazonRekognition rekognitionClient = AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        logger.log("connected to rekognition client");

        DetectLabelsRequest request = new DetectLabelsRequest()
            .withImage(new Image().withS3Object(new S3Object().withName(photo).withBucket(bucket)))
            .withMaxLabels(10).withMinConfidence(75F);
        logger.log("created label request");
        
        try {
            DetectLabelsResult result = rekognitionClient.detectLabels(request);
            logger.log("ran detectLabels");
            List <Label> labels = result.getLabels();
            logger.log("Detected labels for " + photo);
            for (Label label: labels) {
                logger.log(label.getName() + ": " + label.getConfidence().toString());
            }
            response = new AnalyzeTrickResponse(200);
            
        } catch (AmazonRekognitionException e) {
            response = new AnalyzeTrickResponse(400, "Unable to Analyze Trick: " + input.toString() + "(" + e.getMessage() + ")");
        }
        return response;
    }
```

When I step through, it times out at:

```
DetectLabelsResult result = rekognitionClient.detectLabels(request);
```

Comment: have you verified that any outbound connections are allowed?  could this be a firewall issue?

Comment: I have the lambda function in a vpc if that's what your asking. Sorry I'm relatively new to AWS

Comment: Does the Lambda service role has the necessary policy for Rekognition usage? Policy example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html

Comment: Yes, I allowed full access for rekognition

Comment: If this is deployed in a VPC, the most likely reason why this is hanging is that there is no outbound internet access.  This could be due to no internet routes in the subnet's routing table (either internet gateway or NAT gateway) or, less likely, the security group or NACL preventing outbound internet access.

Comment: Gotcha, that was the problem. I needed to add an endpoint to my VPC